# How can I stop Exoplayer v2 when playing an RTSP stream and restart the stream?

Tags: android, rtsp, exoplayer2.x

I am developing an Android app that will subscribe to one of multiple RTSP streams produced by live cameras connected to a Jetson device. The Jetson portion of the project is working properly. I can enumerate all the cameras and create a RTSP stream with each. I can open and play the RTSP stream locally on the Jetson with no latency. I have access to a video player app on Android that can open and play the RTSP stream with no latency, but I don't have access to the code so I can't see what is used in the app.
Currently, I am using Exoplayer but I am unable to stop and restart the stream and latency is ~2sec.
I previously used VideoView which allowed me to stop and restart the stream but latency was ~5sec.
Ideally latency would be close to 0 (a couple hundred ms would be fine.
I definitely need to be able to stop, restart, and switch streams.
I have scoured the internets and tried all sorts of stuff with no success.
Any help would be appreciated.

1. In my app I have tried using VideoView, and I am able to stop and restart the stream, and I can switch between the cameras. But I have a latency of ~5sec, which is unacceptable.
2. I have also tried using Exoplayer v2. I can start stop a stream, but I can't restart the stream or switch cameras. I get the below stack trace. Also, I can get latency down to ~2sec (not great, but better than 5sec).

If anyone can help with either part 1 or 2 above, that would be awesome.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
      com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:620)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.240.190 (port 8554) from /:: (port 44452): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:187)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:595)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:475)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:243)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:279)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient.getSocket(RtspClient.java:304)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient.start(RtspClient.java:198)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaPeriod.prepare(RtspMediaPeriod.java:158)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MaskingMediaPeriod.prepare(MaskingMediaPeriod.java:145)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.maybeUpdateLoadingPeriod(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:2002)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.updatePeriods(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1982)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:974)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
        at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:201)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:158)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:201)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:201)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:179)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230) 
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212) 
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:646) 
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:595) 
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:475) 
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:243) 
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:279) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient.getSocket(RtspClient.java:304) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspClient.start(RtspClient.java:198) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaPeriod.prepare(RtspMediaPeriod.java:158) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MaskingMediaPeriod.prepare(MaskingMediaPeriod.java:145) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.maybeUpdateLoadingPeriod(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:2002) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.updatePeriods(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1982) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:974) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:502) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Here is the code.

```
public class GenericUVCFragment extends Fragment {

    private static Logger LOG = null;
    private Context context;
    private FragmentGenericUvcBinding binding;
    MessagePublisher messagePublisher;

    private ExoPlayer player = null;
    private MediaSource mediaSource = null;
    Button playButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentGenericUvcBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        messagePublisher = new MessagePublisher();
        context = getContext();
        LOG = ALogger.getLogger(context, GenericUVCFragment.class);

        playButton = (Button)binding.buttonThird;

        binding.buttonSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String resetResponse = messagePublisher.sendEvent("reset");
                messagePublisher.close();
                if (player != null) {
//                    player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
//                    player.release();
                    player.removeMediaItem(0);
                }
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(GenericUVCFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_GenericUVCFragment_to_FirstFragment);
            }
        });

        binding.buttonThird.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String buttonText = playButton.getText().toString();
                // send message to play or pause video
                if (buttonText.equals("Play"))
                {
                    playButton.setText(R.string.stop);
                    String response = messagePublisher.sendEvent("Play");
                    if (response.equals("starting camera"))
                    {
                        if (player == null){
                            binding.playerView.requestFocus();
                            LoadControl customLoadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                                    .setBufferDurationsMs(10, 200, 10, 10)
                                    .build();
                            player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
                                    .setLooper(context.getMainLooper())
                                    .setLoadControl(customLoadControl)
                                    .build();
                            player.setVideoSurfaceView(binding.playerView);
                        }
                        PlayVideo();

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    playButton.setText(R.string.play);
                    player.removeMediaItem(0);
                    messagePublisher.sendEvent("Stop");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void PlayVideo()
    {
        String videoPath = "some url here";
        mediaSource = new RtspMediaSource.Factory()
                .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoPath));
        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare();
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```